# Installing OMV on Raspberry Pi 4 via installScript

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

System:
Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64 bit), Debian version: 11 (bullseye)
Connected via LAN and Wifi not configured
Installed OMV6 refering https://github.com/OpenMediaVault-Plugin-Developers/installScript

Command:

```
sudo wget -O - https://github.com/OpenMediaVault-Plugin-Developers/installScript/raw/master/install | sudo bash
```

Visting Raspberry IP on Firefox browser, the default login credential does not work
Error:
400 - Bad Request
Incorrect Username and Password

```
user: admin 
password: openmediavault
```

SSH disabled on host.

Looking for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After careful observation,

The unix user and OMV default user names seemed to be same as "admin"

So the default OMV admin user password doesnot validate.